# c# calling a list of a class into another class

Tags: c#

so im trying to call a class into a method. but it gets mad because this method isnt calling for a list and the class i made is a list. i tried making a separate variable that isnt a list but it didnt seem to work when i ran the program.

Its the "egg.BounceRock(rocks);" under the run method on the World Class;

**World class**

```
public class World
{

    private List<Rock> rocks;
    private Egg egg;
    private Board board;

    private Graphics graphics;
    public World()
    {
        egg = new Egg();
        board = new Board();
        rocks = new List<Rock>();
        rocks.Add(new Rock(graphics, new Point(RockstartX, RockstartY), Color.Black));
        rocks.Add(new Rock(graphics, new Point(Rock2startX, Rock2startY), Color.Black));
    }
    public void Run()
    {
        foreach(Rock rock in rocks)
        {
            rock.Draw();
        }
        egg.Draw();
        egg.BounceRock(rocks);
        egg.BounceBoard(board);  
        egg.BounceFloor();          
    }
 }
```

**Egg class**

```
public class Egg
{

    public Egg()
    {

    }
    public void Draw()
    {

    }
    public void BounceFloor()
    {

    }
    public void BounceBoard(Board board)
    {

    }
    public void BounceRock(Rock rock)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Not clear, why do you pass a list if the method accepts a single `Rock`? Either provide an overload that accepts a list, pass a single `Rock` or use a loop.

Comment: You `public void BounceRock(Rock rock)` should be something like `public void BounceRock(IEnumerable<Rock> rock)`

Comment: `it gets mad` <= maybe you get mad? PCs (*code running on a PC)* do not get mad, if you have coded something that gets mad let me know because you will be the first person to actually have created AI, a pretty cool thing.

Comment: Your method accepts **1** `Rock`. You must change the `BounceRock` method signature to accept a list, or your calling of that method to pass a single rock instead.

Comment: How is  `BounceRock` supposed to know which rock to bounce when it expects one, and you pass it many? Pass a single `Rock`, or change the definition of `BounceRock`.

Comment: Can you just change the method to accept a list? `public void BounceRock(List<Rock> rock)` Either that or you can add it to your foreach loop and call `egg.BounceRock(rock);` after `rock.Draw();`

Comment: sorry im still a bit new to all this. trying this out now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Egg
{
    public void BounceRock(Rock rock)
    {
        // Bounce the rock...
    }

    public void BounceRocks(List<Rock> rocks)
    {
        foreach(Rock rock in rocks)
        {
            BounceRock(rock);
        }
    }
}
```

So your egg knows how to bounce a single rock, but it does not know how to bounce a collection of rocks... yet! By adding a new method that takes a list of rocks as a parameter, you can loop over every rock in the list and use your original bounce method to bounce each one.

Comment: Instead of `List<Rock> rocks` it would be better to use IEnumerable as the method does not care if its a List, Collection, Array, etc as long as it can be iterated. `public void BounceRocks(IEnumerable<Rock> rocks)`

Comment: Then `BounceRock(Rock rock)` should be `private` since looks like you are trying to encapsulate it

Comment: @Igor Totally agree, but was deliberately keeping it as simple as possible for the OP

Comment: And i thank you for that :p, havent touched on IEnumerable yet so was quite confused. But what you provided worked perfectly thank you very much.